# Toggle div with CSS animation and Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to add an animation to a div the I'm im showing and hiding with a button click. I have the animation that I want but I don't know how to make a button in JS run that CSS animation.. Could someone please help me?

https://codepen.io/mattmcgilton/pen/JjjbGMB

```
.reveal-content {
    animation: slide-in-fwd-center 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) both;
}


 @keyframes slide-in-fwd-center {
    0% {
      transform: translateZ(-1400px);
      opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
      transform: translateZ(0);
      opacity: 1;
    }
  }
```

```
var x = document.getElementById("reveal-content").style.display = "none";

document.getElementById("btn-reveal").addEventListener('click', function() {
    var x = document.getElementById("reveal-content");
    if (x.style.display === "none") {
      x.style.display = "block";
    } else {
      x.style.display = "none";
    }
});
```

Comment: This is very odd-looking Java

Comment: Could it be JavaScript instead? Hmmm

Comment: Language tags edited

Comment: any help would be appreciated

Comment: How can I help you? You tagged the question as a Java problem, I know Java, but I don't know JavaScript -- please tag carefully

Comment: ah sorry my mistake

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `max-height` for the element and the apply transition for hiding and showing. Check the snippet below

```js
document.getElementById("btn-reveal").addEventListener('click', function() {
  let el = document.getElementById('reveal-content');
  if (el.classList.contains('hide')) {
    el.classList.remove('hide');
  } else {
    el.classList.add('hide');
  }
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
}

#reveal-content {
  max-height: 1000px;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
}

.hide {
  max-height: 0 !important;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" id="btn-reveal" class="btn">Button</button>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="reveal-content" class="hide">
    <h2>Hide me and then reveal me</h2>
    <div id="json-content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc scelerisque dui magna, imperdiet ultricies felis pellentesque nec. Aenean iaculis tellus porttitor sapien sagittis, eu dapibus dui ultricies. In gravida arcu leo, sit amet convallis quam
        tincidunt tempus. Aliquam eget suscipit tortor. Maecenas eget nunc eu risus auctor lacinia. Nulla et sapien sed urna ultrices pretium non ac purus. Quisque sed egestas augue. Aliquam sit amet vulputate tortor. Sed condimentum tellus eu placerat
        feugiat. Nullam quis eros sed magna venenatis condimentum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed posuere lacinia facilisis. Curabitur sit amet porta dui.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div>Rest of the page...</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS code is already taking care of the displaying part. You don't need to do that again with JavaScript. What you are looking for is the classList.toggle() method. This will add and remove the .reveal-content class on a click event. This is what your JavaScript code should be:

```
var div = document.querySelector("div");
var button = document.getElementById("btn-reveal");
button.addEventListener('click', function () {
   div.classList.toggle("reveal-content");
});
```

EDIT:

```
        var div = document.querySelector("div");
        var button = document.getElementById("btn-reveal");
        button.addEventListener('click', function () {
            if(div.classList.contains('slide-in-fwd-center')) {
                div.classList.add("slide-out-bck-center");
                div.classList.remove("slide-in-fwd-center");
            }
        });
        button.addEventListener('click', function () {
            if(div.classList.contains('slide-out-bck-center')) {
                div.classList.add("slide-in-fwd-center");
                div.classList.remove("slide-out-bck-center");
            }
        });
```

In your CSS code only one of the classes (either .slide-in-fwd-center class or .slide-out-bck-center class) will be applied as a default.

Comment: thank you. would you take a look at this codepen for me? I now have a class for the fade in and 1 for the fade out. How would I toggle the toggle fade in to work with the first click and then fade out on the second click? and this would just repeat through the two classes with each click

Comment: In this case you'll need to use the classList.add() and classList.remove() method. I'm editing my answer in accordance with your current code.